# rxjs post many delete request and update view at last

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Code below will call updateView  many times, I want to run it once at last.

```
import {from} from 'rxjs';
const ids = [1,2,3,4,5...999];
const subscribe = from(ids).subscribe(val => {
    console.log(val);
    this.updateView();
});
```

online example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rxjs-run-at-last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`last`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/last.html) operator.

> Emit the last value emitted from source on completion, based on provided expression.

```
import {from} from 'rxjs';
import { last } from 'rxjs/operators';

const ids = [1,2,3,4,5...999];
const subscribe = from(ids).pipe(last()).subscribe(val => {
    console.log(val);
    this.updateView();
});
```

Your [forked StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rxjs-run-at-last-oyq4ny)